# while reading excel sheet in java it tends to skip one cell value and auto populate it with next colomn

Tags: java

I am trying to read excel file cell by cell.The problem i am facing is ,my program skip one cell value while reading the excel file. Below is the code.

```
private void ReadExcel {

         try
          {

             FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\abc.xlsx"));
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); 
          //Create a blank sheet
          XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
          //Create row object
          HashMap<Integer,List> hm = new HashMap<Integer,List>();
          Integer index = 0;

          //This data needs to be written (Object[])
          Iterator<Row> rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
          while (rowIterator.hasNext())
          {
              List cellDataList = new ArrayList(); 
              Row row = rowIterator.next();
              //For each row, iterate through all the columns
              Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

              while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
              {
                  Cell cell = cellIterator.next();               

                      switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                      {
                          case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:                            
                              if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                                  //System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                                  cellDataList.add(cell.getDateCellValue());
                              } else {
                                  //System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                  cellDataList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                              } 

                              break;
                          case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                              //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                              cellDataList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                              break;
                          case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                              //System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                              cellDataList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());


                      }


                 }
              hm.put(index, cellDataList);
              System.out.println("Size of hashmap  is  " +hm.size());
              List al =hm.get(index);
              System.out.println("List Size is " +al.size());
              for(int i = 0;i<al.size();i++)
              {
                  //System.out.println(" " +al.get(i));

              }
              System.out.println();
              index++;            
              System.out.println("");

          }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Exception " +e);

          }

    }
```

Input data file i am passing to method is [image]

I shared the input file screen shot. The problem i am facing is , i am able to read all cell value of first row  and get the size of 4 but when i read second row , value of coloumn "D" is getting skip and getting size of 3. I dont why its skip the second row "D" Coloumn.

Comment: Try to insert a default case in your switch.

Comment: @chf : Already tried with default case.Stiil issue is same.

Answer (score 0):

use normal for instead

do something like this

```
 Row oRow = sheet.createRow(rowCounter);
  for (short cell = 0; cell < row.getLastCellNum(); cell++) {
                    System.out.println("Reading Cell number: "+cell);
                    Cell cell0 = oRow.createCell(cell);
                    cell0.setCellValue(row.getCell(cell).toString());
                }
```